# Should I include being an interviewer on my resume?

Tags: interviewing, resume

I am not the manager of the team I work on but was the first hire in it and have conducted dozens of interviews making a significant contribution to the assembly of a successful team of a handful of programmers. I take a lot of pride in conducting interviews and consider it a skill of mine. Should I mention this on my resume?

Comment: **for sure**, it's key.  good language would be:  *key member of the hiring staff.  Conducted 6 general interviews, 7 technical interviews, 4 final interviews.* and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you think interviewing skills are directly related to the position you're applying for, sure, put it on there.  if it's not directly related to the position, you can still include it, but maybe put it down towards the bottom of the list.  (Nice to know you can do it, but keep the focus on the skills that are actually relevant.)

That being said, if you're going to make a point about how good you are at conducting interviews on your resume, you better make damn sure you leave a good impression when you're *being interviewed.*